# Jquery append couldn't work with setInterval

Tags: javascript, php

From console log i can see that POST request is being sent to the page specified in the ajax URL every 3 seconds. Howbeit, the code could not append new dynamic result from the page after the first append. Am i getting something wrong?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    function load_friend_request() {

        $.ajax({
        url: "/friend_requests_main_loader.php",
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(html) { 
            //$("#friend_request:last-child").empty();
            $("#friend_request").append(html);
        }
        })
    }

    setInterval(function() {
        load_friend_request();
}, 2000);


});
</script>
```

The #friend_request

```
<div id="friend_request" class="control-icon has-items">
        <svg class="olymp-happy-face-icon"><use xlink:href="svg-icons/sprites/icons.svg#olymp-happy-face-icon"></use></svg>
</div>
```

The PHP code

```
<?php
echo time();
?>
```

I expect the script to append new result every 3 seconds from a PHP script, it only work the first time the page is loaded.

Comment: can you show your friend_requests_main_loader.php and #friend_request html?

Comment: Have made some modifications

Comment: First, thing, did you check your console for js syntax error? Second, why are you appending time(); why there is not like html code?

Comment: `echo "<div class='label-avatar bg-blue'>{$count}</div>"`

Comment: I just added that one as example, what i appended was `echo "<div class='label-avatar bg-blue'>{$count}</div>"`

Comment: No error in console

Comment: as long as you have an element with id = friend_request there's no reason that wouldn't work

Comment: Thanks, have seen the error, after the first call chrome automatically remove the id from the parent how do i go about that?